# How to select most recent txt file from directory in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to select the most recently modified file from my server using javascript.

This is the code in my js files:

```
$.get('Dropbox/geo/sites/GC_ROOM/hassayampa.txt', function(data){   
        // Split the lines
        var lines = data.split('\n');   
        // Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
        $.each(lines, function (lineNo, line) {
            var items = line.split('\t');
            if(lineNo !== 0) {
               var x = + new Date(items[0]),
                    primout = parseFloat(items[3] / 10.0),
                    secout = parseFloat(items[5] / 10.0);
                if(!isNaN(primout) && !isNaN(secout)){
                    options.series[0].data.push([x,primout]);
                    options.series[1].data.push([x,secout])
                }
            }
        });
        new Highcharts.Chart(options); // this is now in the $.get callback function
    });
```

Here is coding from the index.php file that views the js files:

```
<body width="100%">
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://geoinc.org/css/GEOREMCO/graph/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://geoinc.org/css/GEOREMCO/graph/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="monitor/SiteData/Data/Lane_Metals/GRAPH/LANE_METALS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="monitor/SiteData/Data/Lane_Metals/GRAPH/LOVELAND.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="monitor/SiteData/Data/Lane_Metals/GRAPH/TEST.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="monitor/SiteData/Data/Lane_Metals/GRAPH/APPLES.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="monitor/SiteData/Data/Lane_Metals/GRAPH/EXAMPLE.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="monitor/SiteData/Data/Lane_Metals/GRAPH/FRUIT.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0" width="10%" bgcolor="#E8E8E8">
        <tr>   
            <th><div id="TEST" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div></th>
            <th><div id="EXAMPLE" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div id="LANE_METALS" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div></td>
            <td><div id="FRUIT" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><div id="LOVELAND" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div></td>
           <td><div id="APPLES" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Thanks again everyone!

Comment: Javascript runs on the client-side, PHP on the server-side. How do you expect to access internal server resources from the *client-side*?

Comment: This is not possible, unless that `Dropbox/....` URL is on the SAME server as the JS code was loaded from, and includes file timestamps in its output listing.

Comment: the folder "Dropbox" is on my local server, it can be accessed through my directory. Like I mentioned, I am able to find the most recent file using php code but I cannot do it using js (javascript). The reason why I want to use the code in js is because the file that the js reads is a txt file that is constantly updating. In summary, a txt file is sent to my server, a js file reads said txt file, an index.php file reads the js file that makes the graph that is shown on my website [http://www.geoinc.org/test.php](http://www.geoinc.org/test.php)  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best solution for this would be to have a JavaScript GET request to your PHP application that handles access to your Dropbox.

From what you explained your Dropbox is only visible serverside and you want to expose your TXT files client side, to solve your current problem add a method, PHP side, to handle file access to your dropbox and expose it so your client side JavaScript can request the contents from your PHP application.

Comment: That sounds great! If I understand correctly you suggest the js file get a variable from my php file that points to the most recent file.

Comment: Yep, your JS has to do a GET (look into jQuery GET) request to your PHP file that returns the source of your TXT file based on the parameters you are sending to your PHP file "/test.php?dropbox=file1" or "/test.php?dropbox=file2"

Comment: I think it would be too much extra work to add more script to my index.php file. There must be someway to locate the most recent file there in the same js script right before parsing it out.

Comment: I can help you if you have an issue but not with your code, this is not a place where some one writes a whole solution for you. There should be a lot of tools online that either already solved your problem or solves it in a way where you just need to modify it.